# How do I perform object manipulation on an asynchronous result object?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I was wondering how I can manipulate a JS object from one file, in another, asynchronously.
I don't really have a lot of experience with asynchronous code principles.

**Situation:**

I have a file, `app.js`, in which I dynamically create 'app panels' based on my HTML.

```
$("div.app-panel[data-panel]").each(function() {
        // create panel objects for all html divs with class app-panel
        var panel = {};
        panel.div = $(this);
        panel.name = $(this).attr("data-panel");
        panel.isActive = ($(this).attr("data-active-panel") == "true" ? true : false);

        panel.onActive = () => {
            // default functionality to execute when activating an app panel
            panel.isActive = true;
            $(panel.div).attr("data-active-panel", true);
        };
        panel.onInactive = () => {
            // default functionality to execute when deactivating an app panel
            panel.isActive = false;
            $(panel.div).attr("data-active-panel", false);
        };

        app.panels.push(panel);
    });
```

Now I want to be able to override the onActive method in my other file, `main.js`, but how do I know if this code has finished running?
I can't apply `.filter()` or `.find()` on app.panels, it will return undefined.
I can `console.log(app.panels)`, and it will return the array to my console... but I can't do:

```
panel = app.panels[0]
```

this will give me undefined.

I tried to create a function inside of object `app`, which accepts a callback function that will use app.panels as parameter. This however gives me the same results...

Then I tried to solve it this way:

```
app.getPanels = async () => {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(app.panels);
    });
    return promise;
};


var getPanels = async (callBack) => {
    const appPanels = await Promise.all(app.getPanels());
    console.log(appPanels);
    callBack(appPanels);
}
```

this raises the error "TypeError: object is not iterable".

Anyhow, I think my code makes it quite clear that I am not familiar with promises at all, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promisers aren't the solution here. It's all to do with coordination of code loaded from different files.

A typical strategy would be for :

- all .js files except "main.js" to contain classes/functions, but not execute anything.
- "main.js" to coordinate everything by creating class instances and calling functions/methods.
- "main.js" to be loaded last.

Comment: I have already met all those requirements, what else could I do?
Edit:
Nevermind, my app.js initializes the app panels, tonight I will try to do this in my main.js

Comment: By executing code only inside of main.js I fixed it, thankyou!

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with it.